# 1 long beep followed by 3 short beeps

Tags: boot, motherboard

I was trying to replace a faulty DVD drive in my pc.

I changed it and now when I boot I get 1 long beep and 3 short beeps.

There seems to be conflicting information on what this means. I have tried the following :

- put back the old dvd drive
- swapped the memory around, I have 2 sticks so I have tried every combo of slots with 1 or 2 sticks. It seems unlikely to me that *both* memory sticks are broken, but is that a possibility?
- taken out gfx card

Each change still fails with 1 long beep and 3 short beeps

The motherboard I have is a gigabyte ga-b75m-d3h. When I get the gigabyte docs for bios beeps it says it's an AGP error, not sure what to do about that.

I am at a bit of a loss, any ideas beyond replacing everything?

**UPDATE**

On another forum someone suggested taking out the mobo battery thing to reset the bios. My computer does boot now. However, I dont get any video out from the gfx card but I can from the onboard gfx. I would've assumed this means the gfx card is broken, but if it truly was broken i would expect it not to boot at all. Does anyone know any more about this?

Comment: Disconnect EVERYTHING from the board, except for the processor. Remove all of the RAM and then reseat a single stick and see if you can get it to boot with no BIOS beeps.

Comment: Search for the manual that came with your motherboard, and look up the error codes. Errorcodes are not the same for every motherboard.

Comment: Disregard my last comment. I just looked up the manual and its not in there. :(

Comment: Are you sure its AGP? Your mobo is too new for that.

Comment: Re: your update. There is probably a setting in the BIOS which tells it whether to use the on-board video or an add-in card.

Comment: ... On page 36 of [the manual](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-b75m-d3h_e.pdf): Init Display First.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AGP's a video card port (maybe that's from an old webpage but it still could be "video problem")... maybe your video card got knocked loose or something's disconnected or failed. Tried removing & re-seating it, everything's plugged in? Any other video cards to try?

Or use onboard video? If that works, I'd suspect the video card has gone bad (or had something disconnected or knocked loose).

Clearing the BIOS was probably required to get it to "reset" and use the onboard video, instead of trying & failing to use the video card. Even with a malfunctioning video card, you might be able to use the onboard video successfully.

Comment: Sadly I dont. On another forum someone suggested taking the mobo battery out and trying again. Interestingly it now boots fine but nothing is coming out of the graphics card, onboard one does work

Comment: Edited answer a bit, hardware failures can be tricky, booting with a bad card might work, up until you try to use the card for something. Onboard video means the video card can just sit there quietly... At least you're not stuck & still have onboard video

Comment: Yeah I think I'll probably just order a replacement gfx card and see if that fixes it. Otherwise return it to Amazon..